# How to make a Bind in SqlDataSource - Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is how I should be able to update a product on the page, it must grasp the category which I have chosen, so I will be free to save my choice every time.

I chose to do it via SqlDataSource dropdownlist.

I have written the code like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
        runat="server" 
        CssClass="form-control" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        DataTextField="navn" 
        DataValueField="Id"
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("kategori") %>'
        ></asp:DropDownList>

    <%--datasource--%>
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' 
        SelectCommand="SELECT kategori.id, kategori.navn, produkter.fk_kategori FROM kategori INNER JOIN produkter on kategori.id=produkter.fk_kategori ORDER BY [Id] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It appears this one error:

**Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"
```

What should I do to the grasp it I've chosen category.

Comment: your selected value must be SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id") %>',  why you are using sqldatasource you can bind it manually..

Comment: is your `ddl` is inside any databound control?

Comment: @Rahul Where can I find a good solution to the task, - Maybe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945922/gridview-edititemtemplate-dropdownlist-get-selectedvalue

Comment: Your error message is self explanatory! Also, when you want to show a single value to be selected, are you passing one? No! You are passing the column name of complete query, but it expects a single value.